# Create tree hierarchy in json.net with LINQ using c#

Tags: c#, linq, json.net

I looked at this [Create tree hierarchy in JSON with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3153674/create-tree-hierarchy-in-json-with-linq)  question and answer and it's close to what I need. However I can't generate the nested array as shown below as I am using json.net

***Class.cs***

```
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Attribute> test { get; set; }
    }
    public class Attribute
    {
        public string testKey { get; set; }
        public string start { get; set; }
        public string finish { get; set; }
        public string comment { get; set; }
        public string status { get; set; }
    }


    public class AttributeData
    {
        public Attribute AttributeDataOps()
        {
            ***Attribute DATA***
        }
    }
```

***Program.cs***

```
Attribute attribute = new Attribute();
AttributeData attributeData = new AttributeData();
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(attribute);
string path = @"C:\file.json";
```

***Expected Result***

```
{
    "tests" : [
        {
            "testKey" : "",
            "start" : "",
            "finish" : "",
            "comment" : "",
            "status" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

***Current Result***

```
    {
        "testKey" : "",
        "start" : "",
        "finish" : "",
        "comment" : "",
        "status" : ""
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your expecting a collection but your passing a single object to serialize.

```
var rootObject = new RootObject();
List<Attribute> attribute = new List<Attribute>();
rootObject.test = attribute;
string JSONresult = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootObject);
```

Comment: the list<attribute> portion cannot be shown. Do I need to create a object for that?

Comment: You need to add value to it